# Extracting clusters from matrix

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matrix where the first and second column represent x, y-coordinates and the third column is cluster ID:

```
95.0129    5.7891    3.0000
23.1139   35.2868    1.0000
60.6843   81.3166    2.0000
48.5982    0.9861    3.0000
89.1299   13.8891    3.0000
76.2097   20.2765    3.0000
45.6468   19.8722    3.0000
 1.8504   60.3792    1.0000
82.1407   27.2188    3.0000
44.4703   19.8814    3.0000
61.5432    1.5274    3.0000
79.1937   74.6786    2.0000
92.1813   44.5096    2.0000
73.8207   93.1815    2.0000
17.6266   46.5994    1.0000
40.5706   41.8649    1.0000
93.5470   84.6221    2.0000
91.6904   52.5152    2.0000
41.0270   20.2647    3.0000
89.3650   67.2137    2.0000
```

I want create the matrix of individual cluster ID with its x, y coordinates using MATLAB, for example cluster 1: `c(1)= [23.1139   35.2868; 1.8504   60.3792; 17.6266   46.5994; 40.5706   41.8649]`.

Comment: Please, post questions, which could be useful for others, and could have some historical value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your matrix, let's call it `A`, you can do:

```
>> A(A(:,3)==1,1:2)
ans =

   23.1139   35.2868
    1.8504   60.3792
   17.6266   46.5994
   40.5706   41.8649
```

`A(:,3)==1` is a logical column vector, which is true for the rows where `A(:,3)` is equal to 1 (i,e, cluster ID 1). Next, we index `A(x,1:2)`, with `x` the logical column vector, selecting rows, and `1:2` selecting the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I would extend Cris's answer s.t. you automatically create all of your clusters at once using arrayfun:

```
C = arrayfun(@(id) A(A(:,3)==id, 1:2), unique(A(:,3)), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

This will create you a cell array per cluster.

As talked about with Cris, this would be a possibility if you have skipped cluster ids, or something like that you could store them in a map:

```
cluster_ids = unique(A(:,3));
cluster_map = containers.Map(cluster_ids, arrayfun(@(id) A(A(:,3)==id, 1:2), cluster_ids, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

And then access it with the id `cluster_map(3)`

Comment: Nice! I'd add to this: if `C{n}` must be the coordinates for cluster `n`, then use `1:max(A(:,3))` instead of `unique(A(:,3))`.

Comment: That is a valid remark. However I just assumed that id's are all given / used. If this is non-trivial I think I would start putting them into a containers.map.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; As i consider x,y-coordinates represent the location of the nodes in x,y-plan and i assume the nodes in each cluster are correlated based on overlapping. I want to compute the correlation coefficient by first compute the euclidean distance between the nodes and then using exponential model to compute correlation coefficient for example c(1,1) = exp(-d(1,1)) then i can get matrix for each cluster. Thank you